# Remove 'Homegroup' and 'Network' from left pane?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-8.1

How can I go about removing the 'Homegroup' and 'Network' tabs in the left pane of the explorer in Windows 8.1? I tried [Windows 7 Navigation Pane Customizer](http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-navigation-pane-customizer-show-hide-rename-items-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane/), but it was very glitchy and didn't work (obviously, because it's for Windows 7).

[image]

Comment: try this tool: http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213